# I want to enter title at the top the table and some data at bottom using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have printed a table that was in csv format using pandas library of python but I want to add title and some data in the bottom of the table before printing.

This my python code for printing table

[image]

I want my table to be printed like this with title: Table 5: Nauru Weighted Point System and at the bottom: State = 0 A = 8/Winner B = 5.82 C = 6.65

[image]

Comment: can't you use `print()` before and after `head()` ? Eventually you will have to rewrite all code inside function `head()`. Or maybe it may change templates in `to_html()`

Answer (score 0):

This example might lead you in the right direction..

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

my_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'Voters':['V1','V2','V3','V4'],
                              'True Preferece':['B>A>C','C>B>A','A>C>B','B>A>C'],
                              'Declared preference':['A>B>C','B>C>A','C>A>B','A>B>C'],
                              'Weights':[3,2,4,2]})
#my_frame Display pandas table

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.table(cellText = my_frame.values,
          rowLabels = my_frame.index,
          colLabels = my_frame.columns,
          loc = "center"
         )
ax.set_title("Table 5: Nauru Weigted Point system")

ax.axis("off");
```